# How to connect Neo4j with Zest?

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, zest

In Java, I have a Neo4j EmbeddedGraphDatabase. How can I transform this into a Graph that Zest can display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try Neoclipse, a standalone RCP app using ZEST, http://neo4j.org/download/ and https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse